# Recursive type upcasting with templates

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

I work with containers.

If `A` is a container then `container_traits<A>::reference_container` must type an `A`.

If container `RefContainer<C>` is_base_of `A`, then `container_traits<A>::reference_container` must type a `C`.

The following code does this upcasting (or dereferencing, as I say).
The problem is that, even if `reference = false` compiler checks if `C::reference_container` exists as type, and fail to compile.

Any other approaches?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename C> struct RefContainer;

template<class C>
class container_traits
{
    template <typename R>
    static std::true_type ref_helper(const RefContainer<R>&);
    static std::false_type ref_helper(...);
public:
    constexpr static bool reference = decltype(ref_helper(std::declval<C>()))::value;
    typedef typename std::conditional<reference, typename C::reference_container, C>::type reference_container;
};

template<typename C>
struct RefContainer : public C { typedef typename container_traits<C>::reference_container reference_container; };
struct Container1 {};
struct Container2 {};
template<typename C> struct D : public RefContainer<C> {};
struct E : public RefContainer<D<RefContainer<Container1>>> {};

int main()
{
    container_traits<Container1>::reference_container e; // It is Container1
    container_traits<RefContainer<Container1>>::reference_container f; // dereference to Container1
    container_traits<D<Container2>>::reference_container // dereference to Container2
    container_traits<E>::reference_container h; // dereference to Container1
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just create helper class

```
template<class T, bool der>
struct hlp
{
   typedef T type;
}

template<class T>
struct hlp<RefContainer<T>, true>
{
   typedef T::reference_container type;
}
```

Comment: Last 2 lines in main() failed to arrive on Container1. This happen because with this approach, you catch only RefContainer and not classes derived from RefContainer.

Comment: @Chameleon missed this thing, I changed answer. Use it instead of std::conditional